# WinSCP timestamp retrieval from command line/scripting

Tags: command-line, sftp, winscp

How do I get the last time stamp of a `.txt` file from WinSCP when using `.txt` and `.bat` scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should better state, what do you want to do with the timestamp. You might get better answer then.

Anyway:

1. WinSCP has the [`stat` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_stat):

   ```
   stat /home/martin/index.html
   ```

   Outputs something like:

   ```
   -rwxr--r--   0                       20480 Jan  5 14:09:33 2009 index.html
   ```

   You can redirect the output of the WinSCP script to a file and parse.

   Or even better use [XML logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml) and parse the XML log.
2. Easier solution may be to make use of WinSCP .NET assembly method [`Session.GetFileInfo`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfileinfo).

   An additional example (to those linked in the method documentation) is here:
   https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_stat#net